# How does it follow that $y_j \ge 0$ for each $j$ in this proof of minmax theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, game-theory

I'm reading the lecture note about minmax theorem in zero-sum game. First are the relevant definitions used in my lecture notes:

> **A finite zero-sum game**, or **matrix game**, is given by a real-valued matrix $A = (a_{i,j})$ in $\mathbb R^{n \times p}$.
>
> $I = \{1,...,n\}$ and $J = \{1,...,p\}$.
>
> The set of **mixed actions** of Player 1: $$\Delta(I)=\left\{x= (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \,\middle\vert\, \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}=1\right\}$$
>
> The set of **mixed actions** of Player 2: $$\Delta(J)=\left\{y=(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \,\middle\vert\, \sum_{j=1}^{p} y_{j}=1\right\}$$
>
> A row $i$ in $I$ (column $j$ in $J$) is assimilated to the Dirac measure on $i$ ($j$) and is now called a **pure action** of Player 1 (Player 2) in the matrix game $A$.
>
> The **payoff function** is $$\forall x \in \Delta(I), \forall y \in \Delta(J): g(x, y) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{p} x_{i} y_{j} g(i, j)$$
>
> The payoff $g(x,y)$ can also be written as the matrix product $xAy$, where $x$
> is seen as a *row vector* and $y$ as a *column vector*.

The minmax theorem is then stated as follows:

> For any matrix $A$ in $\mathbb R^{I \times J}$, $$\min_{y \in \Delta(J)} \max_{x \in \Delta(I)} x A y=\max_{x \in \Delta(I)} \min_{y \in \Delta(J)} x A y$$

My professor goes on to prove the theorem:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

---

**My question:**

At the end of the proof, my professor said that

> Because of the form of $C$, it has to be the case that $y_j \ge 0$ for each $j$

I'm unable to understand this argument. Could you please elaborate more on it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of $C$, if $z \in C$, then $z' = z - u \in C$ where $u \geq 0$. Therefore, if there exists $y_j < 0$, you can make $u_j$ as large as you want, and therefore the right hand side of your inequality as large as you want, which will violate the inequality. Hence, $y_j$ must be $\geq 0$ for each $j$